# PHP session permissions

Tags: php, session, permission-denied

I'm coding a website for a startup and am currently having trouble saving session data to keep users logged in. When I try to use session variables or `Zend_Auth` I get this:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/data/session/session id, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

I tried running this script from another similar question and got that the directory isn't writeable.

```
$path = session_save_path();
if (is_dir($path)) {
    echo "directory exists\r\n";
    echo (is_readable($path) ? "directory is readable\r\n" : "directory is not readable\r\n");
    echo (is_writable($path) ? "directory is writable\r\n" : "directory is not writable\r\n");
}
else "directory does not exist\r\n";
```

So I changed the permissions on `/data` and `/data/sessions`, but even when they are set to `777` I still get the same message. I then tried running this script from another question about the same problem.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$s = stat('/tmp');
printf('%o', $s[2]);
file_put_contents('/tmp/phptest1234.txt', 'test');
unlink('/tmp/phptest1234.txt');
```

This returns `41777`. From the same question, checking the umask returns:

```
php-umask: 22
exec-umask: 0022
```

What does this mean and how can I go about fixing it?

Comment: Is this your own server or are you using a shared hosting environment? Also, did you install your server and PHP yourself or did you use something like cPanel or XAMPP?

Comment: What OS are you using?  If you have SELinux, permissions of 777 may still not be sufficient to write to the folder.  You could change the `session.save_path` directive in `php.ini` to save session data to a directory owned by your user (or the user that the server runs as).  What does `<?php echo get_current_user() ?>` show when you run it from the browser vs who owns `/data` and `/data/sessions`?

Comment: Any reasons to not use the default session_path?

Comment: @BorisGuéry, security reasons. But still not good enough since he's setting 777

Comment: @AdnanShammout, why would it be more secure?

Comment: @BorisGuéry, PHP has read/write access to `/tmp/` meaning that any user on the server can write a little PHP script to view session data and possibly alter them. (Most of the low-level hosts are ill-configured)

Comment: @AdnanShammout, I don't get your point, even if sessions are stored in the `tmp/` dir and as far as permissions/umask are set correctly you can't read session without `www-data` user.

Comment: @jaimerump, do you have a shell access? If you do, please do `ls -alh /data/sessions` and give us the result

Comment: The server is an Apache server running CentOS and is hosted through hivelocity.net. `/data/sessions` was the default session save path set on the server, though it didn't exist when I first started having the problem. The shell command returns `drwxr--r-- 2 trengine trengine 4.0K Jun 18 12:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 trengine trengine 4.0K Jun 18 12:46 .`

Comment: Also, `get_current_user()` returns trengine.